# Meteor(React) - Add cron job for aws meteor project

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, cron

I have added cron job for my meteor app at aws by using following command:

*** * * * * curl -v http://example.com/testcron**

But looks like it is not working as I am not getting any results which is visible if I am trying to refresh http://example.com/testcron manually.

Also tried '/usr/bin/curl' instead of curl but no effect.

What to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

2 things I can think of:

Ensure that curl is installed on the instance and, in your path.

Check the logs and/or enable more verbose logging to see what’s happening with cron.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Tried whereis curl and result is curl: /usr/bin/curl /usr/share/man/man1/curl.1.gz which is right I guess.

Comment: if the cron logs show the job is executing succesfully and, curl runs from the command line without any exception errors then that rules those 2 things out. If the command produces output results when you run it manually from the command line maybe try and put “curl -v http://example.com” in quotes. If the command won’t produce results when ran manually then the problem lies elsewhere.